# Function object is not subscriptable

Tags: python

```
    # TensorFlow and tf.keras
    import tensorflow as tf
    from tensorflow import keras
    
    # Helper libraries
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import os 
    import cv2
    
    print(tf.__version__)
    
    DATADIR ="D:\Datasetes\legen"
    CATEGORIES = ['light']
    
    for category in CATEGORIES:
        path = os.path.join(DATADIR,category) #to create a path to the image in our drive
        for img in os.listdir(path):
            img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img),cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
            plt.imshow(img_array , cmap="gray")
            plt.show
            plt.figure()
            plt.imshow(img_array)
            plt.colorbar()
            plt.grid(False)
            plt.show()
            break
        break
    
    class_names = ['light', 'power', 'capture']
    train_images.shape
    len(train_labels)
    train_labels
    train_images = train_images / 255.0
    train_labels = train_labels / 255.0
    
    test_images = test_images / 255.0
    test_labels = test_labels / 255.0
    
    def class_names():
        for category in CATEGORIES:  
    
            path = os.path.join(DATADIR,category) 
            class_names = CATEGORIES.index(category)  
    
            for img in (os.listdir(path)):  
                try:
                    img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img) ,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)  # convert to array
                    new_array = cv2.resize(img_array, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))  # resize to normalize data size
                    training_data.append([new_array, class_num])
                except Exception as e:  
                    pass
         
 
    import random
    random.shuffle(training_data)
    img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img),cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
    for i in range(10):
        plt.subplot(5,5,i+1)
        plt.xticks([])
        plt.yticks([])
        plt.grid(False)
        plt.imshow(img_array, cmap='gray')
        plt.xlabel(class_names(train_labels)) 
        plt.show()
        break
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-147-400073625620> in <module>
     29     plt.grid(False)
     30     plt.imshow(img_array, cmap='gray')
---> 31     plt.xlabel(class_names(train_labels))
     32     plt.show()
     33     break
```

TypeError: class_names() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

this is the code that I am using and it keeps on giving an error as ''function' object is not subscriptable.I have added the whole code into this. please help as this is a school project and it is included in my goddamn GPA the error happens in the line with :the last part of the code

Comment: More information is required for people to help. On which line does the error occur? Please include the error message.

Comment: Hey man, welcome to StackOverFlow, I'm quite new to so it helps to post useful information on your title, and content, if everybody used your title it would make life so much worse wouldn't it? Try to make your title summarize the problem, appreciated

Comment: Please read the following article on how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Why is this tagged tensorflow2.0?

Comment: it occurs on the plt.xlabel   line

Comment: No wonder. That line uses `train_labels`, which isn't defined anywhere. There's other undefined stuff in your code, too. Please include the rest of your code, or produce a smaller example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable' in Python 3.4.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32446402/typeerror-function-object-is-not-subscriptable-in-python-3-4-3)

Answer (score 0):

The name class_names is used both as a variable and also as a function name.Hence there is an ambiguity when you do

```
class_names[]
```

First Used here

```
class_names = ['light', 'power', 'capture']
```

Then here

```
def class_names():
```

After this class_names is no longer a list but a function.

Then, when you do

```
class_names[something] - it is an error
```

Comment: okay thank you I removed that now it gives me a syntax error on the plt.show line

Comment: File "<ipython-input-143-b64793609ab7>", line 32
    plt.show()
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: its plt.show(). You are missing the braces at line 31

Comment: i added into the code againa s i am reciving another error